# The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am using SAP crystal reports in my wpf application, I am getting this exception at the time of initialization

```
ExportOptions _ExportOptions = new ExportOptions();
```

this is the error I am getting:

> The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions' threw an exception.

and this is inner exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"}

Total inner exception including message is in this [link](http://pastie.org/8439181) (external Web site).

I tried to add the dll reference of the particular version, even though it is still showing the same issue. I am very worrying about this issue as I could not figure out the solution for a long time.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: have you checked this post? http://scn.sap.com/message/14048680 I had the same problem with log4net assembly, and this was my solution

Comment: I am using SAP Crystal Reports Version 11. @JRB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that you don't have the runtime for CR installed correctly. A lot of people make the mistake and install the runtime using the msi installer instead of the exe. The msi does not integrate CR with VS, the exe does. As Raphael pointed out in his comment, this [post](http://scn.sap.com/message/14481406) has a very good thread and explanation by Ludek, who is one of the sharpest minds at SAP. You can download the exe [here](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe).

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Which runtime version should I need to install in my 64bit pc where I have Visual Studio 2010, presently I am using Crystal Reports Version11.

Comment: You should install the latest 32 bit version. Crystal is a 32 bit application.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have installed CrystalReports Version 13 and that problem is resolved but I am getting another new problem. Here is error link http://pastie.org/8453768 and my xaml code http://pastie.org/8453681 and this error is coming when I try to generate the report.

Comment: To be honest with you, I have no idea. I suggest to start a new question with that error and put appropriate tags to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced same issue , i had change my projects Target framework to **.NET Framwork 4** . you can change the same from project property->Application tab ->Target framework.

Comment: The target framework is set to .Net Framework 4 only @JRB. I tried to change the Platform target to Any CPU from x86, even though the issue still persists.

Comment: after that you should restart project. also ckeck below link.http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/crystal-reports-and-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: also https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560630/vs-2010-net-4-cannot-found-crystalreports-references#